# Correlation, Feature Importance in R

Tags: machine-learning, r

If I have 150 features, with the output feature being nominal(multi-class), how can I verify which features play a key role in determining the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given class, you may usually treat the problem as a binary classification (the given class versus all others). You can do the same for your feature importance calculations. However we won't be able to help you much outside of a given problem and a given model, as available feature importance solution depends on the model used.